# Convert integer matrix to bitstring?

Tags: matrix, bit-manipulation

I have a `4x4` integer matrix (called `tb`) which I can create from a `int64_t` bitstring (called `state`) as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        ipos -= 1;
        tb[i][j] = (state >> (4*_pos)) & 0xf);
    }   
}
```

Once I start with a matrix, however, how can I change it to a bitstring? I was hoping to go through the integer matrix, get the element, create a 4 bit hex representation of it, then shift it over (`<<4`) the correct number of times and bitwise or (`|`) the bitstring with the new `state` bitstring, but I'm not sure how to do this or if it is the best way. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just do it exactly how you said, something like this (not tested)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        pos--;
        state |= (uint64_t)tb[i][j] << (4 * pos);
    }   
}
```

This has a fairly long dependency chain, that's not great especially if you're in HPC. You could chop it up into parts, say the first half and the second half, then combine them in the end. As a bonus that means the shifts operate on 32 bits rather than 64, which may be faster on some platforms.

Depending on the type of `tb` there may be other tricks, for example if every entry is a byte and you can alias it with two `uint64_t`'s, then you can combine the entries using straight line bitmanipulation (though they are "reversed" compared to the most convenient order).

For example, maybe something like this (not tested) (this assumes the ordering is reversed, it can also be done with the same order)

```
uint64_t low, high; // inputs
uint64_t even = 0x00FF00FF00FF00FFULL;
uint64_t odd = ~even;
low = (low & even) | ((low & odd) >> 4);
high = (high & even) | ((high & odd) >> 4);
even = 0x0000FFFF0000FFFFULL;
odd = ~even;
low = (low & even) | ((low & odd) >> 8);
high = (high & even) | ((high & odd) >> 8);
low = (low & 0xFFFF) | (low >> 16);
high = (high & 0xFFFF) | (high >> 16);
return low | (high << 32);
```

If you allow special instructions there is an even shorter way, (not tested, and again reverses the order)

```
low = _pext_u64(low, 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0FULL);
high = _pext_u64(high, 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0FULL);
return low | (high << 32);
```

The related conversion the other way is equally simple,

```
low = _pdep_u64(bitstring & 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0FULL);
high = _pdep_u64(bitstring >> 32, 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0FULL);
```

Both of these also apply to the reversed order if you just reverse the nibbles first, which can be done with bitmanipulation as well.